# Can't submit facebook app for review

Tags: unity, facebook

I'm trying to submit my app for review with publish_action.

I keep getting the following error:

"It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

I'm publishing posts to the users' feed with Facebook SDK for Unity.:

```
 FB.Feed(link: LinkToApp);
```

I've filled all the necessary fields.

I posted both from the Graph and from an iOS device and I still get the same error when I try to submit for review.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

On your FB.Login make sure you request the action

```
public void FBLogin()
{
    FB.Login("email, publish_actions", AuthCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a test user (which you have given publish_actions permission in the settings, then the  request action for 30 days will disappear.